# How to execute a function which requires gas using web3 & React?

Tags: web3js

I have the call working for a non-gas execution.

This code below does not seem to run. Should I add account in the call?

```
let addContract = async (inputValue) => {
    var abi=
  [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"contractWeight","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"jsonInput","type":"string"},{"name":"hashKey","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"addContract","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"weight","type":"uint256"}],"name":"addWeight","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"contracts","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]

    var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/'));
    var contractaddress= "0xb316b4bf742818d3fb97586a2f3aea361b240f30";

    var hashVal = web3.utils.sha3(inputValue);
    console.log(hashVal);

    let commodityContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractaddress);
  //  let newContract =   commodityContract.at(this.state.contractAddress);
  //  this.setState({commodityContract: commodityContract});
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.coinbase;
  //  var testResult = commodityContract.contracts(test1);
    var result='';
    commodityContract.methods.addContract(inputValue,hashVal).call().then(
       (result) => console.log(result)
     );

    console.log(commodityContract);

}
```

Comment: You probably want `send`, not `call`.

Comment: Yes send and also the account to charge the gas should be given. I am unsure how that is done.

Comment: I believe `web3.eth.defaultAccount` should take care of that. You can use `send({ from: '0x123abc...' })` if you want to override the default.

Comment: I am just checking into this. I was wondering about security. I am using Ropsten. So I am unsure what the default account will be. The system needs to prevent theft so there must be some kind of key system.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see you're using Infura. You can't just use `send` then, because Infura doesn't know the private key for your account. (That has nothing to do with Ropsten vs. the main network, it's just that you're using a public node.) If you want to use a public node directly, you'll need to sign transactions locally (with a private key) and then send them via `sendSignedTransaction`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it adding few parameters in `call()`:

```
    const response2 = await contract.methods
       .createNewCertificate("11111111","gdsfgdsfgdsfg","gdsfgdsfg",["gdsfgdsfg"],["gdsfgdsfg","11111111111"])
       .send({
            from:accounts[0], 
            gasPrice : this.state.web3.utils.toWei("5", "gwei"), 
            gas : this.state.web3.utils.toWei("0.0000000000005", "ether")});
```